# What is "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" in WiFi setting?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi, modprobe

One of the common solutions for improving WiFi signal is to use this command

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

in

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

And the number can be `0`, `1`, `2`, `8`.

I was unable to find a manual for this command. What do these numbers do? And how should we choose among the available options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the terminal command:

```
modinfo iwlwifi

parm: 11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
```

I am unaware of and have been unable to locate further documentation.

> And how should we choose among the available options?

In most cases, if the router is set up optimally, that is, WPA2-AES and not any mixed mode, and set to a fixed channel, not auto-channel select, we need none of them.

However, if we are connecting at work, university or a library where we have no option to reconfigure the router to suit our preferences, it is sometimes helpful to try each in turn until we connect reliably. Generally =8 is most helpful, followed by =1. I have never encountered a case helped by any other of the other options.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was terrible upload speeds on just some WiFi networks, on Ubuntu 19.04. Neither 11n_disable=1 nor 11n_disable=8, the two settings I've seen recommended, worked for me; the former improved upload speeds but cut download speeds in half, and the latter did nothing. I experimented and found that 11n_disable=2 boosted my upload speed by 700%, but at the price of decreasing my download speed by 12%. That's a reasonable tradeoff when otherwise the upload speed is unusable, but I didn't want to take the decreased download speed on WiFi networks whose upload speed was fine without changing the setting. So I wrote a script to check with WiFi network I'm using and adjust the setting accordingly. I published it on my blog (https://blog.kamens.us/2019/08/03/mitigating-wifi-upload-speed-issues-on-lenovo-ideapad-s340-running-linux/) with more details in case it might be useful to others.

However, I know Stack Exchange doesn't like answers to depend on external links, so here's the script. It needs to be installed as root, mode 0755, in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

WHOAMI=$(basename $0)
IFACE="$1"; shift
ACTION="$1"; shift

log() {
    level="$1"; shift

    logger -p daemon.$level -t "$WHOAMI" $@
}

if [ "$ACTION" != "up" ]; then
    log debug ignoring action $ACTION
    exit 0
fi

state=$(cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/11n_disable)

log notice previous 11n_disable state is $state

if [ "$CONNECTION_ID" = "bad-wifi-network-name" ]; then
    want_state=2
else
    want_state=0
fi

if [ "$state" != "$want_state" ]; then
    log notice reloading iwlwifi with 11n_disable=$want_state
    if ! rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi; then
        log err rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi failed
        exit 1
    fi
    if ! modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=$want_state; then
        log err modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=$want_state failed
        exit 1
    fi
    if ! modprobe iwlmvm; then
        log err modprobe iwlmvm failed
        exit 1
    fi
    log notice finished reloading iwlwifi with 11n_disable=$want_state
else
    log notice 11n_disable is correct, taking no action
fi
```

Comment: in my case, no value other than 1 works for me. the Wifi adapter simply fails to connect to the Wifi. `dmesg` output indicates `association with <MAC> timed out`