# Wifi disconnects randomly on Kubuntu 20.04 KDE Plasma Version 5.18.5 Kernel version 5.4.0-52 generic while power management is disabled

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kubuntu, kde

running `lspci` i get:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

Power management is set to leave unchanged for all situations.
Wifi shows connected but stops working. Looking at the inbuilt network upload and download speed shows a connection to the network and my router does detect the machine but I lose internet access. KDE Wallet is known to cause issues but it has been disabled (was never enabled). I have tried running on multiple bands and on both 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz.

running `spci -nnk | grep -i network -A2`
output:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095b] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5210]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

running `rfkill list all`
output:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
running iw dev gives:
phy#0
        Unnamed/non-netdev interface
                wdev 0x3
                addr 34:02:86:44:74:ac
                type P2P-device
                txpower 0.00 dBm
        Interface wlp4s0
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                addr 34:02:86:44:74:ab
                ssid AasraAirtel
                type managed
                channel 11 (2462 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2462 MHz
                txpower 21.00 dBm
                multicast TXQ:
                        qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes        tx-packets
```

I have tried adding a static IP to as well as disabling IPV6 still no difference.

`iwconfig` gives:

```
usb0      no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"AasraAirtel"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 64:2C:AC:72:69:54   
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=21 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1219  Invalid misc:410   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, some recommend `swcrypto=1` , `11n_disable=8` options for `iwlwifi` kernel module. Would you try each one following these: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Troubleshooting or https://askubuntu.com/q/1099671/26246